# C++ - In Range and Character

Tags: c++

I am making a system where the user inputs numbers on the console and add them eventually. The problem I have is, if the user inputs a character rather than a number, the program would tell there is an error or it can not add because there was a character inserted on the system. I made the system with if-else-else-if, but that took me ages to code since I placed || functions like for example:

```
if (x=="a" || x=="b" || x == "c" ) ....
```

and so on...

Is there a way for C++ to detect that if the input value is a character or a string, the program would have an error.

Comment: C++ is a typed language, so the type of `x` is what you declared it to be. No more, no less. Now, if you ask about the value it contains, it will depend on the type of the variable _and_ how it is assigned. But you shown none of these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

```
if ( x >= 'a' && x <= 'z' )
```

will tell you if `x` is between `'a'` and `'z'` (similar for capital letters).

Comment: Is `x` a `char` at this point? What are you using to read the value from the user?

Answer (score 1):

There are character classification functions in the standard library that will do all this work for you. `isdigit` is a good place to start.